# How do I integrate and test Google Classroom for a web application

Tags: google-classroom

I'm really confused on how I adapt my existing web application to work with Google Classroom. I currently have a local authentication system for teachers and students, but how does a teacher or school connect their Google Classroom authentication to mine?  How do I test that authentication, and test the API access to the student lists.  I feel like I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding of how Google Classroom works, but I also can't find any documentation on "How to bring your app to Google Classroom".

Answer (score 0):

I don't access Google Classroom through Web platform but I was able to communicate with the Classroom API in this open-source Android application :  [Classroom Client](https://github.com/maleeqB/Classroom-Client).

You claim you already an authenticating system, like I don't know how that works but all you just have to do is get a Client ID as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth).

Once authorized you can execute various API calls supported by the API, there is a reference [here](https://developers.google.cn/classroom/reference/rest?hl=cs)